# SKSpriteNode memory leaks

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, sprite-kit

I am working on a fairly complex SpriteKit game in Swift 4.0.

After I did a memory leak test on it, I found out I have plenty of them. Can anyone point me why do these object leak and what I am doing wrong?

[image]

For example, lets take the `background`.  I declare it globally and I only set the position, size and texture. All my objects will be his children.

```
// on viewDidLoad
background.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ms_background")
background.size = CGSize(width: screen_width, height: screen_height)
background.position = CGPoint.zero
background.zPosition = -1
addChild(background)
```

Another example is `zen_button`. This is all the code I have on it:

```
// after background declaration

zen_button_string = "ms_zen_untap"

zen_button.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ms_zen_untap")
zen_button.position = get_object_position(object_name: "ms_zen")
zen_button.size = get_object_size(object_name: "ms_zen")
zen_button.zPosition = 1
zen_placeholder.addChild(zen_button)

// on touchesBegan,Moved and Ended i check if the user has his finger over the 
// button, in order to change between tap/untap image

if (zen_placeholder.frame.contains(point) && zen_button_string == "ms_zen_untap")
{
   zen_button.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ms_zen_tap")
   zen_button_string = "ms_zen_tap"
}
else if (!zen_placeholder.frame.contains(point) && zen_button_string == "ms_zen_tap")
{
   zen_button.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ms_zen_untap")
   zen_button_string = "ms_zen_untap"
}
```

Why the compiler yells that I have a memory leak and how it is happening?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you should conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable names (`zenButtonString` for instance), don't use snake_case.

Comment: Don't declare background globally. Put it inside your scene class somewhere.

Comment: It’s declared in my scene class. Still, global declaration it’s not a reason for memory leak.